# Should you attach error handler to all Get Records actions in Flows?

Tags: visual-workflow

I'm pretty inexperienced with Flows but have been tasked to add exception loggers to all my Flows.

I've noticed Get Records actions have a Fault Path hence wanted to find out:

- What are the failure modes when getting records?
- Is this a common failure?
- What sort of exceptions to expect
- How can I simulate them?
- is it a good practice at all to have these handlers?

Answer (score 0):

Having good error handling is always a plus, It gives you a way to peer into your processes to be able to understand what's going on & possibly to log it somewhere else and show the user a "nice" error screen.

While uncommon, certain errors do happen;

- https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000IOQCQA4
- invalid ID errors
- Too Many SOQL queries can occur.

My take is its a 5 minute job, especially if you make a common screen or error logging system that you can connect all your fault paths too, so its worth doing, just in case.